# Setear variable luego de almacenar variable en la memoria del dispositivo

Tags: reactjs, storage

En un componente tengo la siguiente sentencia:

```
const [home, setHome]=useState(false)

if(home){

return(<Redirect push={true} to="/" />);
}

setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user)
setHome(true)
```

Es decir, que luego de que es guardada la variable con el indicador "isRegistered", home es igual a true y se debe volver a la vista de inicio. El problema es que inicio es renderizado antes de que se guarde la variable "isRegistered". ¿Cómo puedo setear home=true **luego** de que se guarde efectivamente la variable en el storage?

La función setItem está definida de la siguiente manera:

```
export async function setItem(key: string, value: any) {
  await Storage.set({
    key: key,
    value: value
  });
 }
```

He intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user).then(() =>{
setHome(true)
})
```

Pero sin éxito

Comment: Parece ser un caso de [`race condition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) entre `setItem` y `setHome`, pues ambas son asincrónicas, (los hooks son asincrónicos)

Comment: Pero debería ejecutarse setHome luego de que setItem termine

Comment: Parece que ese `redirect` del `if` nunca va a pasar, pues tienes la variable `home` con un valor `false` por default, siempre que devuelvas ese componente `home` valdrá `false`, ¿Y si validas el if con la variable de `local storage`? Es decir si el usuario ya esta registrado entonces redirecciona. Saludos